# Token22 create/update metadata using metaplex

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, metadata, token-2022, mpl-token-metadata

The token was created using the Token22 program and the metadata was added directly to the mint account as described in the documentation:

https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#metadata

Because the token name and icon are not showing on Solana explorers we are trying to create/update its metadata using Metaplex.

Create metadata code part:

```
    const onChainData = {
        ...ourMetadata,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0,2),
        creators: none<Creator[]>(),
        collection: none<Collection>(),
        uses: none<Uses>(),
    }
    const accounts: CreateV1InstructionAccounts = {
        mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
        splTokenProgram: SPL_TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    }
    const data: CreateV1InstructionData = {
        ...onChainData,
        isMutable: true,
        discriminator: 0,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
        collectionDetails: none<CollectionDetails>(),
        ruleSet: none<PublicKey>(),
        createV1Discriminator: 0,
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        decimals: none<number>(),
        printSupply: none<PrintSupply>(),
    }
    const txid = await createV1(umi, {...accounts, ...data}).sendAndConfirm(umi);
    console.log(bs58.encode(txid.signature))
```

The full code is available on [Github](https://github.com/loopcreativeandy/video-tutorial-resources/blob/main/metadataUpdate/mpl_token22.ts)

The error we are getting is the following:

```
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
'Program log: IX: Create',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program log: Metadata pointer extension: authority must be None',
'Program log: Invalid metadata pointer',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 14738 of 200000 compute units',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0xc4'
```

If we try to update the token metadata we are getting the following error:

```
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
'Program log: IX: Update',
'Program log: Incorrect account owner',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 8849 of 200000 compute units',
'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x39'
```

Adding `metadata` and `authority` options under the `UpdateV1InstructionAccounts` does not make any difference

```
        const onChainData = {
        ...ourMetadata,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        creators: none<Creator[]>(),
        collection: none<Collection>(),
        uses: none<Uses>(),
    }
    const accounts: UpdateV1InstructionAccounts = {
        mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
        metadata:fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadata),
        authority:signer
    }
    const data : UpdateV1InstructionDataArgs = {
        data: some<Data>(onChainData),
    }
    const txid = await updateV1(umi, {...accounts, ...data}).sendAndConfirm(umi);
    console.log(bs58.encode(txid.signature))
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot create a metadata account using Metaplex Token Metadata if your Token 2022 mint has the metadata extension enabled.

You can find the list of supported Token 2022 extensions on Token Metadata here: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/token-2022